# Edit RTF as plain text but unable to open it again

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, stream, rtf

I have a RTF file that I want to open, replace a String "TEMPLATE_Name" and save. But after saving, the file cannot open correctly again. When I use MS Word, the file opens and shows the RTF raw code instead the text.

I am afraid I am breaking the format or the encoding but I don't really know how:

```
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(1000))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms,Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            using (Stream fsSource = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/LetterTemplates/TestTemplate.rtf"), FileMode.Open))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fsSource,Encoding.UTF8))
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    String line = sr.ReadLine();
                    line = line.Replace("TEMPLATE_Name", model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName);
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }

            ms.Position = 0;

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/LetterTemplates/test.rtf"), FileMode.Create))
                ms.CopyTo(fs);
        }
```

Any idea about what could be the issue?

Thanks.

SOLUTION: One problem was what @BrokenGlass has pointed out, the fact I was not flushing the stream. The other was the encoding. In the fist line of the RTF file I can see:

```
{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\
```

So, even without understand anything about RTF, I set the encoding to code page 1252 and it works:

```
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(1000))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms,Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
        {
            using (Stream fsSource = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/LetterTemplates/TestTemplate.rtf"), FileMode.Open))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fsSource,Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    String line = sr.ReadLine();
                    line = line.Replace("TEMPLATE_Name", model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName);
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }

            sw.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/LetterTemplates/test.rtf"), FileMode.Create))
                ms.CopyTo(fs);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you write directly to disk instead of holding it in memory first?

Comment: Because the intention is to send the stream to another component, this is just a prof of concept of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StreamWriter` is buffering content - make sure you call `sw.Flush()` before reading from your memory stream.

[`StreamWriter.Flush()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx):

> Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered data
>   to be written to the underlying stream.

**Edit in light of comments:**

A **better** alternative as @leppie alluded to is restructuring the code to use the using block to force flushing, instead of explicitly doing it:

```
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(1000))
 {
   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms,Encoding.UTF8))
   {
     //...
   }
   ms.Position = 0;
   //Write to file
 }
```

An **even better** alternative as @Slaks pointed out is writing to the file directly and not using a memory stream at all - unless there are other reasons you are doing this this seems to be the most straightforward solution, it would simplify your code and avoid buffering the file in memory.

Comment: Disposing calls `Close` which in turns calls `Flush`.

Comment: He's using the memory stream inside the using block of the `StreamWriter` - it hasn't been flushed.

Comment: Oops sorry! I didn't expect that! +1 for sharp eye :)

Comment: Nice one. The problem is that if I dispose the StreamWriter, the MemoryStream is disposed as well. So just with a sw.Flush() will do. But still have the problem, Microsoft Word is unable of opening the file, and if I export it to PDF, appears a weird symbol at the beginning. I have checked the file sizes, and even without replacing anything, the new file is 5 bytes bigger than the orignial :(